# Why does the CLDR have superscript two trailing some subdivision names?

Tags: cldr

Example, with CLDR 24, in `common/subdivisions/da.xml`:

```xml
<subdivision type="esri" draft="contributed">La Rioja²</subdivision>
<subdivision type="ess" draft="contributed">Kantabrien²</subdivision>
```

Does the trailing character have a specific meaning? -- I noticed that it appears on multiple locales, always for the same subdivisions.